# How to simulate Ground Penetrating Radar system?

Tags: electrical-engineering, finite-element-method, rf-electronics, electromagnetism

We have a project which requires Ground Penetrating Radar(GPR). We got a student license of NI AWR software and Ansys HFSS (high frequency structural simulator). Are those the correct software for this types of system simulation.

What we mainly want to achieve is finding a proper ready to use circuit to connect antennas if applicable, determine the system requirements by using the simulation outputs and implementing algorithm to read and analyze data gathered form the circuit in MATLAB.

If those software are OK, can you suggest a reference/source/tutorial or whatever to model the system. As far as I understand, AWR works like a 2D environment which makes me confused how to simulate especially the ground side. HFSS seems more appropriate to model the ground layers, voids or objects with different material properties to find EM characteristics. But I am not sure how to combine this with a antenna system.